# Roots Sage Symfony error when using override from template

Tags: php, templates, theme-roots

Currenty I’m building a website with Roots Sage as my template. The template works like a charm. But for the import of vehicles we use a plugin. The override in the /resources/ is working. For example if I place in this file it shows me the title of the document.

But when I use the default formatting of the template it gives me errors like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function listing() on null in /wp-content/themes/mytheme/resources/view/voertuig/single.php:18
```

This is on line 18:

```
<?= $voertuig->listing('merk', 'model', 'brandstof', 'transmissie', 'tellerstand', 'prijs'); ?>
```

I’ve also asked the plugin builder to watch to this problem. He also tried some other things, but also got some errors

```
Notice: Undefined variable: wp_query in /wp-content/themes/mytheme/resources/view/voertuig/archive.php on line 23

Notice: Trying to get property 'found_posts' of non-object in /wp-content/themes/mytheme/resources/view/voertuig/archive.php on line 23
```

When I switch to twentynineteen theme the override works like a charm.

Any ideas of how to fix this issue or is there anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where is `$voertuig` defined in the single.php? Are you using Sage 9 or Sage 10 (alpha)?

Comment: I'm using Sage 9, and the plugin developer said this is a hook on the wp_query